# RedirectToAction — infinite loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I get an infinite loop if the URL contains bad data.

This URL asks to see an ID-related list but provides a bad ID

```
<siteroot>/<client>/Class/Index/-1
```

I detect that bad ID and do `RedirectToAction("Index")` which, without an ID, should show a generic list instead. But when the redirect is routed, the bad ID is still there!

Note the ID is optional for the Index method `public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? yid)`

Thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly pass a null value for id in the redirect

```
 int? badId = null;
 return RedirectToAction("Index", new {id = badId});
```

You can't assign `id = null` directly in the anonymous route value object, so you need the preceding line to set id to null.  I don't know what `yid` is, but you may need to expicitly set that as well, lest the bad id fall into that parameter.

Comment: This works perfectly. If I null the bad ID (either id or yid) and explicitly set both of them in the Redirect, then the code responds correctly to either or both of the values being bad. BTW, I think you meant to say either `badId` or `newId` in both places, above.